# Creating JAR file and using in command prompt?

Tags: java, jar, cmd

Okay so I already followed the Java tutorial for creating a JAR file and even creating the Manifest.txt that goes along with it. I am highly confused and I got to the point where I was running the JAR in the command prompt but it wasn't referring to the other class I was using in my main program.

I have two .class files that I am using, `javagame.class` and `sound.class`.

It was finally loading the main class but when it needed to refer to the `sound.class` file it was saying that it doesn't exist, a `NoClassDefFoundError`

I did 'jar cfm myjar.jar Manifest.txt javagame.class sound.class' in the cmd prompt then

```
jar cfe app.jar javagame javagame.class
```

Finally I did `java -jar app.jar` to run the JAR and I got the error above where it couldn't find the sound.class file.

Somebody please help I'm highly confused.

Comment: Probably the two `class`es are not in the same loaction (or folder). Take a look at my answer... it's much easier.

Comment: better show your Manifest.txt file.

Comment: Are you sure that your main class (javagame.java) actually has a `public static void main(String args[])` method? It must have one or else it won't work.

Answer (score 6):

Consider a directory structure for your .java & .class file:

```
HelloWorld(root directory)
   |
   |\src\HelloWorld.java
   |
   |\classes\mypackage\HelloWorld.class
```

HelloWorld.java will look like

```
package mypackage;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args){
       System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

To compile and get the class file in classes folder use the `-d` option in javac
like:

```
F:\HelloWorld\src>javac -d ../classes HelloWorld.java
```

to add all .java files you can use *.java

To create a executable jar of HelloWorld execute the below command from classes directory:

```
F:\HelloWorld\classes>jar cfe HelloWorld.jar mypackage.HelloWorld mypackage/HelloWorld.class
```

after the jar command the options cfe means:

1. **c**: indicates that you want to create a JAR file.
2. **f**: indicates that you want the output to go to a file rather than to stdout.
3. **e**: overrides the manifest's Main-Class attribute.

---

Finnaly, to run the generated jar file, execute below command:

```
F:\HelloWorld\classes>java -jar HelloWorld.jar
```

Output: HelloWorld

Suppose, If you want to specify your own manifest.mf file, then go for

```
jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.txt mypackage/*.class
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite *off* you request, but nonetheless, it is **much, much simpler**.
I'll demonstrate how to create a `JAR` file using [`BlueJ`](http://www.bluej.org/).

1. Open BlueJ and the project that contains all your code. (You can
   import non-bluej : go to *Projects*, *Open Non BlueJ* and then selct
   the folder containing your code.) [image]
2. Go to *Project* and select *Create Jar File...*. Select your *Main class* (Here, it is `NumberSystems.java` for me). The rest you can customize...[image]
3. Save your file...[image]

And you're all done! As simple as that. You can now execute this from `cmd`.